# costume fit with variable parameter

Tags: matlab

I am looking for a way to find a value from diagram fit. I just want to know that is it possible in MATLAB? Is there a code line for this purpose?

For example:

I have two matrix data as follows:

```
X=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]

Y=[9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1]
```

I want to fit these data with nonlinear equation (costume fit) like this:

```
a*(w+1)*x^w*exp⁡(a*x^(w+1))  ;   a=gamma ((w+2)/(w+1))
```

But this equation has a variable parameter `w`. I want to MATLAB give me the `w` that for this parameter I can get a best fit for my data.

Answer (score 0):

use [`fit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fit.html) for curve fitting:

```
% define function as a string
f = 'gamma((w + 2)/(w + 1))*(w + 1)*(x.^w).*exp( gamma((w + 2)/(w + 1))*x.^(w + 1) )';
X = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9];
Y = [9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1];
% define fit parameters
fitType = fittype( f, 'Independent', 'x' ,'coefficients',{'w'});
% fit data
fitobject = fit(X(:),Y(:),fitType,'StartPoint', 0);
% coefficient value
w = coeffvalues(fitobject)
% plot
plot(X,Y,'.');
hold on
plot(fitobject);
title(['w = ' num2str(w)])
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer, and it seems to be right but when I use my data to do the same it give me error like: {Error in fittype expression ==> gamma(((w + 2)./(w + 1)).^(w+1)).*(w + 1).*(x.^w).*exp(-gamma(((w + 2)./(w +
1)).^(w+1)).*x.^(w + 1) )
??? Input must be real and full.

Error in ==> fit at 460
                errstr = handleerr( errid, errmsg, suppresserr );

Error in ==> Untitled at 11
fitobject = fit(s(:),p(:),fitType,'StartPoint', 0);}. I also change f function and X and Y names.